# Fortran: segmentation fault when trying to update particle position in 3-d array

Tags: arrays, module, fortran, fortran90, subroutine

I've written a program to move around particles in a 3-D field based on a 3-D velocity field. However, I get a segmentation fault at the line when I update the particle positions, and I have no idea why! I wrote this program previously in a single file, and it worked fine. But now I'm getting the segmentation fault error when I have all the functions/subroutines in a module.

Edit: I implemented the suggestions below, and now the segmentation fault has moved from the update particle line to the line where I call writeResults. Any help is still appreciated!

Main Program:

```
program hw4Fortran
  use hw4_module
  implicit none

  !Define types
  integer::i ,j, k, num_ts, num_particles, field_size_x, field_size_y, &
  field_size_z, num_arguments
  type(vector),allocatable::vfield(:,:,:)
  type(vector),allocatable::parray(:)
  character(30)::out_file_basename, vel_file, part_file, filename, string_num_ts

  !Read command line
  num_arguments = NARGS()
  if (num_arguments > 1) then
    call GETARG(1, string_num_ts)
    read(string_num_ts, *) num_ts
  else
  num_ts = 50
  end if
  if (num_arguments > 2) then
    call GETARG(2, out_file_basename)
  else
  out_file_basename = "results"
  end if
  if (num_arguments > 3) then
    call GETARG(3, vel_file)
  else
  end if
  if (num_arguments > 4) then
    call GETARG(4, part_file)
  else
  part_file = "particles.dat"
  end if

  !Open files
  open(unit=1, file=vel_file)
  open(unit=2, file=part_file)

  !Read number of particles
  num_particles = readNumParticles(2)

  !Adjust for zero index
  num_particles = num_particles - 1

  !Allocate and read particle array
  parray = readParticles(2, num_particles)

  !Read field size
  field_size_x = readFieldSize(1)
  field_size_y = readFieldSize(1)
  field_size_z = readFieldSize(1)

  !Adjust for zero index
  field_size_x = field_size_x - 1
  field_size_y = field_size_y - 1
  field_size_z = field_size_z - 1

  !Allocate and read vector field
  vfield = readVectorField(1, field_size_x, field_size_y, field_size_z)

  !Move particles and write results
  do i=0,num_ts
  if (mod(i,10) == 0) then
    write(filename, fmt = "(2A, I0.4, A)") trim(out_file_basename), "_", i, ".dat"
    open(unit = 3, file=filename)
  end if
    do j=0, num_particles
      if (i > 0) then
        parray(j) = updateParticle(vfield(INT(FLOOR(parray(j)%x)),INT(FLOOR(parray(j)%y)),INT(FLOOR(parray(j)%z))), parray(j))
      end if
      if (mod(i,10) == 0) then
        call writeResults(3, parray(j))
      end if
    end do
  if (mod(i,10) == 0) then
    close(3)
  end if
  end do

  !Close files
  close(1)
  close(2)

  !Deallocate arrays
  deallocate(vfield)
  deallocate(parray)

end program hw4Fortran
```

Module:

```
module hw4_module
  implicit none

  type vector
    real::x,y,z
  end type

  contains
    function readNumParticles(fp) result(num_particles)
      integer::fp, num_particles
      read(fp, *) num_particles
    end function

    function readParticles(fp, num_particles) result(parray)
      integer::fp, num_particles, i
      type(vector),allocatable::parray(:)
      allocate(parray(0:num_particles))
      do i=0, num_particles
        read(fp, *) parray(i)
      end do
    end function

    function readFieldSize(fp) result(field_size)
      integer::fp, field_size
      read(fp, *) field_size
    end function

    function readVectorField(fp, field_size_x, field_size_y, &
    field_size_z) result(vfield)
      integer::fp, field_size_x, field_size_y, field_size_z, i, j
      type(vector),allocatable::vfield(:,:,:)
      allocate(vfield(0:field_size_x,0:field_size_y,0:field_size_z))
      do i=0, field_size_x
        do j=0, field_size_y
          read(fp, *) vfield(i,j,:)
        end do
      end do
    end function

    function updateParticle(velocity, old_particle) result(new_particle)
     type(vector)::new_particle,old_particle,velocity
     new_particle%x = old_particle%x + velocity%x
     new_particle%y = old_particle%y + velocity%y
     new_particle%z = old_particle%z + velocity%z
    end function

    subroutine writeResults(fp, particle)
      integer::fp
      type(vector)::particle
      write(fp, *) particle%x, " ", particle%y, " ", particle%z
    end subroutine

end module
```

Comment: do you realize you are reading one more  "particle"  than the value of "num_particles"  from the file..?  Not necessarily a proble so long as you are consistent. Likewise "field+size_x" is one more than the size of the array, etc..

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the indexing. But I still get a segmentation fault at the line, `call writeResults(3, parray(j))`

Answer (score 2):

This function

```
function readParticles(fp, num_particles) result(parray)
  integer::fp, num_particles, i
  type(vector),allocatable::parray(:)
  allocate(parray(0:num_particles))
  do i=0, num_particles
    read(fp, *) parray(i)
  end do
end function
```

allocates `parray` with index values `0:num_particles`.  Unfortunately, and this trips up many a newcomer to Fortran (some oldcomers too), those array bounds are not passed out to the calling code which will blithely assume an index range starting at `1`.  And then the code goes on to access `parray(0)` ... and the problem that John B warns of arises.

Fortran's capability of indexing arrays from an arbitrary integer value is never quite as useful as it seems.  You can pass the bounds into and out of procedures, but who can be bothered ?  Easier just to pretend that Fortran arrays index from `1` and apply that consistently throughout a program.

Comment: Oh, interesting. So how can I make sure the calling code knows to start at 0? Am I supposed to allocate it twice, once in each program??

Comment: I see your edits. The instructor asked that we index our Fortran arrays at 0, but I guess it's not a big deal if I do otherwise?

Comment: Okay, @High Performance Mark, I changed the program to 1-indexed and no longer get that seg fault! But I get one at the line `call writeResults(3, parray(j))`

Comment: I'm on this website to get help with problems I can't solve on my own.. This line is only calling `parray(j)`, which seems to be a legitimate call because it works in the updateParticle function, so I don't know what else it could be.

Comment: even though I agree the best sol'n is to not use zero indexing, i'd still like to know how to fix this..  In the calling routing we see `type(vector),allocatable::parray(:)` .  Surely there must be a way to specify the zero lower bound(?)

Comment: @agentp: you raise an interesting question -- why not post it here on SO.  Off the top of my head, and bearing in mind that it is well after beer o'clock here where I am writing, I'm not sure that there is a straightforward approach to allocating an array with index minimum `0` in a procedure and return it to the calling routine.  Perhaps a sourced allocation such as `allocate(array(0:maxindex), source=routine()args))` ???

Comment: hmm, from some testing what he's doing with the allocatable in the calling program doesn't work at all regardless of the lower bound issue. (I'll put an answer here to that .. )

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple version of what the OP is doing with `allocate`

```
module altest
contains  
function setarray(n) result(x) 
implicit none
integer, intent(in) :: n
integer , allocatable :: x(:)
allocate(x(n))
x(1)=1
end function
end module

program Console6
use altest
implicit none
integer,allocatable :: m(:)
m=setarray(2)
write(*,*)'m1',m(1)
end program Console6
```

It "appears" to be allocating an array `x` in the function and assigning that to an `allocatable` array `m` in the calling program.  This compiles but throws a subscript out of bounds error on the `write`. (note this would likely be a seg fault if bounds checking is not enabled )

This can be fixed by separately allocating the array in the calling routine, or by passing the allocatable array as an argument:

```
module altest
contains  
subroutine setarray(n,x) 
implicit none
integer, intent(in) :: n
integer , allocatable :: x(:)
allocate(x(n))
x(1)=1
end subroutine
end module

program Console6
use altest
implicit none
integer,allocatable :: m(:)
call setarray(2,m)
write(*,*)'m1',m(1)
end program Console6
```

Edit - somewhat to my surprise, the second case works fine if we allocate with a zero lower bound in the sub `allocate(x(0:n))` , the calling routine 'knows' the subscript starts at zero.  ( Works with intel fortran v13 -- I have no Idea if this is a safe thing to do.. )

Comment: I tried implementing this (changing the functions to subroutines), and I still get an error, although a different one: `Subscript #3 of the array VFIELD has value 77 which is greater than the upper bound of 1`

Comment: This is in another words the same advice as I gave in the other question, maybe we should have closed that one, but I did not see this question. @JacyReese The change to subroutines was correct and the new error is a different error, this question is a possible correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

A segmentation fault normally indicates that your program is trying to access memory that does not belong to it.

When you say the error occurs "when I update the particle positions", I take it you mean this line:

```
updateParticle(vfield(INT(FLOOR(parray(j)%x)),INT(FLOOR(parray(j)%y)),INT(FLOOR(parray(j)%z))), parray(j))
```

An array-bounds violation in that statement seems entirely plausible, as I don't see anything in your code that would prevent the array indexes `INT(FLOOR(parray(j)%x))` *et al* from falling outside the allocated dimensions of array `vfield`.  Even if they are all in bounds at the initial step of the simulation, they may go out of bounds as the simulation proceeds.

Whether such a result in fact occurs appears to be data-dependent, not related to whether your functions appear in a module.

Comment: Thanks, John. The data files were provided by my instructor, so I assumed they wouldn't lead to such errors. He wrote them so particles would never go out of bounds, or so he said. But I guess if my code is fine, that's what it has to be? For what it's worth, I have an analogous C program that is working correctly with the same data files. Additionally, this occurs before I write the particles from the 10th time step, because my program only produces a "results_0000.dat" file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a C background.  Could this be an off-by-one error?  When looping in Fortran, the loop index goes all the way to the upper bound.  Your Fortran loop:

```
do j=0, num_particles
    ! ...
end do
```

is equivalent to this C loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= num_particles; j++)
{
    // ...
}
```

Note the `<=` sign, instead of `<`.

You may want to change your Fortran upper bound to `num_particles - 1`.

Comment: Thanks! I adjusted the num_particles by 1 when I first read it (easy to miss), so I don't think this is the issue.